# Authenticating users by their IPs in a Active Directory system in Java

Tags: java, linux, active-directory, ldap

Can I authenticate my users by their IPs in a Active Directory system in Java language? I am connected to network by a linux machine. I don't know where I must start form.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/) `SimpleBindRequest` or one of the SASL bind request classes to authenticate LDAP client connections. The client will need at the distinguished name and the credentials for the simple BIND request. The LDAP client should determine how to create a distinguished name from an IP address. 
For example:

```
final String hostname = "the hostname";
final int port = PORT; // sometimes 389
try
{
    final LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection(hostname,port);
    try
    {
        final SimpleBindRequest request = new SimpleBindRequest(bindDN,bindPassword);
        final BindResult result = connection.bind(request);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.close();
    }
}
catch(final LDAPException ex)
{
     handle the exception ...;
}
```

#### see also

- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using an SASL or an Extension.

LDAP has no provision to determine the IP address of a client.

[SASL](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/SASL) is External to the LDAP Protocol

-jim